# Deploying {EAR, WAR} web application on Sun Application Server PE 8 (circa 2005)?

Tags: java, deployment, ejb, war, ear

tl;dr: **How would you deploy a web application if this was 2005?**

I've been trying to deploy a basic {EAR, WAR} for the past 4-5 weeks using Sun Application Server PE 8, J2SE 1.4.2, and my professor's paper from 2005 as reference documentation.

Given the age of the software that I'm developing with, all pertinent reference documentation has been removed from the Internet (as it seems). As programmers who have developed in EJB 3.0 (I'm using EJB 2.1), how would you deploy an application that uses:

- J2SE 1.4.2
- EJB 2.1
- Sun Application Server PE 8
- Sun Deploytool
- JSPs + servlets
- Notepad (IDEs are not permitted)

I've asked at least 4 other questions on StackOverflow trying to get to the bottom of deploying something like a "Hello World" web application in Sun Application Server PE 8 to no avail. Does anyone have a haphazard guess as to what I should do here?

Menu options (new):

- Application
- Application Client
- Connector Resource Adapter
- Enterprise Bean
- Web Component
- Web Service

Menu options (add to application):

- Application Client JAR
- Enterprise JavaBean JAR
- Web Application WAR
- Connector Resource Adapter RAR

**My faulty logic**

- Create EAR application
- Create EJB
- Add Foo.class, FooBean.class, FooHome.class to EAR application
- Create "X" add FooServlet.class, FooClient.jsp (?) to "X"

But, clearly that's incorrect. **If this was 2005, how would you deploy a web application?**

I'm a fool for complying with my course requirements, but if this was 2005...how would you deploy a web application? Should I just use the Wayback Machine?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is](http://futureboy.us/ape/J2EE1.4/docs/QuickStart.html#wp83916) an example from [Quick Start Guide](http://futureboy.us/ape/J2EE1.4/docs/QuickStart.html) to package and deploy a hello world application.

> ### Packaging and Deploying Applications
>
> This section provides information for packaging and deploying applications in the Application Server software.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant Perhaps he knew it would be useful information in the future :P

Comment: Awesome, that must have been it.